# Problem with CSS and Button

Tags: html, css

I have CSS

```
div.myButton input a {
display:block;
height: 24px;
width: 43px;
padding:10px 10px 10px 7px;
font: bold 13px sans-serif;;
color:#333;
background: url("hover.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
}
myButton a:hover {  
background-position: 0 -44px;
color: #049;
}
myButton a:active {
background-position: 0 -88px;
color:#fff;
}
```

And then i have HTML

```
<div class="myButton"><INPUT type="submit" name="" value=""></div>
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong but I'm unable to view the image !!

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
div.myButton input a
```

to

```
div.myButton input
```

and the other 2 to

```
div.myButton input:hover

div.myButton input:active
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/EpyGn/1/

Comment: "div.myButton" is redundant, simply putting .myButton is sufficient. (Two can play at this game)

Comment: hahahahahaha can't breath ... true but since he's using that method im assuming he has a reason maybe he has another element with the same class with input fields then since its not a id but a class it could be a necessity to do so. Just saying doesn't have to be that way, simple put, a possibility.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/EpyGn/ It works but the problem is that.The image is in  the button. I want the image to be displayed instead of the default button . Ex . I want it to be like the "Magnifying lens" as seen as www.entireweb.com

Answer (score 1):

`div.myButton input a` looks for a div with the class `myButton` that contains an input, that contains an anchor. You have no such anchor, so the style is not applied to anything.

Comment: I didn't get you mate ? Can you make the modifications in the current code..I"m not able to understand what you said.

Comment: @541: it isn't clear from your question *where* you want the image to appear, so I wouldn't want to suggest any changes. I'm just saying that *all* the css selectors you've pasted are selecting `a` elements, and you do not have any `<a...>` in your code, so none of those styles are applied right now.

Comment: Ok,Now i get it.But i did change it and check this : http://www.jsfiddle.net/EpyGn/ The image is displayed in the button and "I want the image TO BE THE BUTTON"...Get it ?

Comment: You should've told us :) `<input type="image" src="hover.png" />`

Answer (score 0):

div.myButton {
display:block;
height: 24px;
width: 43px;
padding:10px 10px 10px 7px;
font: bold 13px sans-serif;
color:#333;
background-color:#093;
background:url(images/add.png);
background-image:url(file:///C|/Documents%20and%20Settings/pooja/Desktop/cnn.png)
text-decoration: none;
}
myButton a:hover {
background-position: 0 -44px;
background-color:#093;
color: #049;
}
myButton a:active {
background-position: 0 -88px;
background-color:#093;

color:#fff;
}